# Jquery on click change display

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi guys I am just a beginner and I want to make hamburger menu. I already made a hamburger but when I want my jquery to work nothing happens. Can someone look at my code and tell me what is wrong?

```
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
      crossorigin="anonymous">

          $("#burger-menu").on("click",function(){

          $(".show").css("display","block")


        });

</script>
```

and my html

```
<nav>
   <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div id="burger-menu">
            <img src="img/icons/burger-menu.png" class="menu-burger">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="show"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="show"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="show"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

            <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png"></div>

            <li class="show"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li class="show"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li class="show"><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and I want on click at "burger-menu" to change style of class "show" which is
display: none to display: block

EDIT: I also would like to somehow toggle this classes I mean when I click on this hamburger, "ul" will take display: block but when I click again this will have display: none

Comment: Use jQuery's show(), hide() or toggle() methods.

Comment: I did and still the same:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect that code after src will execute. Move your functions to another script element (better before body closing tag).

As for your question, this should work:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#burger-menu").on("click",function(){
          $("#menu_container").toggle();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Good luck!

Comment: or use the document ready idiom:
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});

Answer (score 0):

Select the `ul` element containing `show` class and `toggle()` its display like this --

```
$("#burger-menu").on("click", function() {
  $("ul:has(.show)").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank for your response and time I really appreciate that:)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not paying attention to your container. You can work from the ul container, instead of the individual menu items.

So give an id to

```
<ul>
```

like

```
<ul id="menu_container">
```

In your CSS you want it to start hidden, so

```
#menu_container { display: none; }
```

Then in your JS you should be able to just use the toggle function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#burger-menu").on("click",function(){
         $("#menu_container").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank for your response and time I really appreciate that:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an element, `e.preventDefault()` is necessary unless your page is going to refresh.

```
    $("#dropdownHead").on("click",function (e) {
        $("#dropdownMenu").toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```