# Why am I not getting a response from serialize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to jQuery. I've been trying to use the .serialize method in jQuery, but I can not seem to garner a response. I've checked console on Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, and Chrome but there's no indication of anything happening past connecting to the latest library (3.4.1). My HTML and JavaScript code are below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascirpt" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="ourform" id="ourform" action=''>
<select name="salute">
    <option>Mr.</option>
    <option>Mrs.</option>
</select>
<br>
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
<br>
<select name="region" multiple="multiple">
    <option>North</option>
    <option>South</option>
    <option>East</option>
    <option>West</option>
</select>
<br>
<textarea rows="6" cols="20" name="comment">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="g" value="submit" id="g"/>
</form>
<div class="results">Your Results</div>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ourform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var myform = $('#ourform').serialize();
        alert(myform);
        return false;
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to put your own code in a different `<script>` tag to the one which references jQuery.js

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. If I do that, however, I get a '$' is not defined error in the console.

Comment: are you using jquery slim library or full?  That may or may not have implications with serialize()

Comment: "I get a '$' is not defined error in the console." Well did you also add the include for jQuery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery on click change display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52909398/jquery-on-click-change-display)

Comment: @davidgamero came up with the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Since it seems you want to disable the default `submit` behavior for the button, adding the `type="button"` attribute removes the need to cancel the default behavior.

When you are including your own javascript within `<script>` tags you don't need the `src` attribute (this was causing the 404)

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidgamero/qamxz65g/7/)

```
    ...
      <button id="g" name="g" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="results">Your Results</div>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#g').click(function(event) {
          //event.preventDefault();
          var myform = $('#ourform').serialize();
          alert(myform);
          return false;
        });
      });

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

The `$ is undefined` is caused by jquery failing to load, which is caused by misspelling 'javascript' in

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascirpt" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js">
</script>
```

Comment: You are correct about the submit behavior, and I updated my answer. My understanding was that the goal was to serialize the form element and its children for some other purpose, not submit the form to a url since we wouldn't have to manually serialize it for that

Comment: Also, never give an element in a form an `id="submit"`.  It's asking for problems with overlaying the submit method on the form.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the id back to the original "g"

Comment: @davidgamero Thanks for your help. I'm still a little bit unsure as to where I went wrong, but I'll study your code and figure out what went wrong. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

You can't include an `src` attribute and have data in the tag - if you have `src`, your script tag must be empty.

Simply use two separate ones:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ourform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var myform = $('#ourform').serialize();
        alert(myform);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but now I'm getting a '$' is undefined in the console.

Comment: @PetePhanor: can you share the full message?